# Returning multiple values to a form from a function

Tags: javascript, forms

I am new to JavaScript and am having problems returning multiple values back to a form.  Here is my code:

The form:

```
<form name="form1">

First option
<input type="text" size="20" name="OptA" rows="1">

Second option
<input type="text" size="20" name="OptB" rows="1">

<input type="button" name="calc" value="Calculate" onclick="Evaluate(document.form1.OptA, document.form1.OptB, document.form1.TheStr);">

<input type="text" size="5" name="TheStr" readonly><input type="text" size="5" name="TheSte" readonly>

</form>
```

The script:

```
function Evaluate(OptA, OptB, TheStr)
{       
    var A_Count = 0;
    var B_Count = 0;
    var C_Count = 0;
    var D_Count = 0;
    var Str1 = 0;
    var Str2 = "";
    var Str3 = 0;
    var Str4 = "";
    var Char1 = "";
    var Char2 = "";
    var Char3 = "";
    var Char4 = "";
    var Total = 0;
    var TheOptions = OptA.value + OptB.value;
    var A1 = "";
        TheStr.value = "";
        TheOptions = TheOptions.toUpperCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < TheOptions.length; i++)
        {
                if (TheOptions.charAt(i) == 'A')
                {       A_Count++;      }
                else if (TheOptions.charAt(i) == 'B')
                {       B_Count++;      }
        }
        Str1 = "" + A_Count+B_Count;
        Str2 = "";
        while ((Str1.length > 2) & (Count < 20))
        {
                Str2 = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < Str1.length - 1; i++)
                {
                        Char2 = Str1.charAt(eval(i+1));
                        Str2 = Str2 + (parseInt(Str1.charAt(i)) + parseInt(Str1.charAt(eval(i+1))));
                }
                Count++;
                Str1 = Str2;
        }
        if (Count > 19)
        {
                TheStr.value = '0%';
        }
        else
        {
                TheStr.value = parseInt(Str2,10) + '%';
        }

    for (var i = 0; i < TheOptions.length; i++)
        {
                if (TheOptions.charAt(i) == 'C')
                {       C_Count++;      }
                else if (TheOptions.charAt(i) == 'D')
                {       D_Count++;      }
        }
        Str3 = "" + C_Count+D_Count;
        Str4 = "";
        while ((Str3.length > 2) & (Count < 20))
        {
                Str4 = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < Str3.length - 1; i++)
                {
                        Char4 = Str3.charAt(eval(i+1));
                        Str4 = Str4 + (parseInt(Str3.charAt(i)) + parseInt(Str3.charAt(eval(i+1))));
                }
                Count++;
                Str3 = Str4;
        }
        if (Count > 19)
        {
                TheSte.value = '0%';
        }
        else
        {
                TheSte.value = parseInt(Str2,10) + '%';
        }

    TheStr=(TheStr.value, TheSte.value)

}
```

For some reason it is only returning a value to the first input box, the second one remains blank.  I guess my problem is figuring out how to return more than one value and then how to parse it into the two input boxes.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both inputs are named "TheStr". You need to name the second input "TheSte" if I understand correctly and also declare it in your Evaluate function.

Edit: Also, the final instruction

```
TheStr=(TheStr.value, TheSte.value)
```

has no effect. In your function TheStr is a text input. You change its value by setting the value property

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, typo, I will fix that.  The second input is named "TheSte."

Comment: Does it work if you pass TheSte to your function like the other inputs ?

Comment: No, it does not. I am sure it is something simple I am missing and I will feel like a total fool when it is pointed out.

Comment: That's because the code doesn't run, Count is undefined. Check the error console, and get firebug to help you find out mistakes. If Count is defined you should get results in both inputs.

Comment: Yes, it turns out I was missing the declaration for "TheSte."  So the first line in the script should read `function Evaluate(OptA, OptB, TheStr, TheSte)` and right under `TheStr.value = "";` there should be `TheSte.value = "";`  And I deleted the final instruction `TheStr=(TheStr.value, TheSte.value)` as you pointed out.  Thanks!